# Get Dataset Property with C# in Lightswitch HTML

Tags: c#, dataset, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a Lightswitch HTML Application which needs a default value on an Add Screen.

> I want to pass the value of `EmployeeID` from my dataset `TBG_V_KeepInTimesheet_Detail` as the default `EmployeeID` value when inserting new records.

My dataset is filtered with the logic

```
partial void TBG_V_KeepInTimeSheet_Details_Filter(ref Expression<Func<TBG_V_KeepInTimeSheet_Detail, bool>> filter)
    {
        // filter = e => e.IntegerProperty == 0;

        filter = e => e.UserLogin == this.Application.User.Name;
    }
```

This filters with their Windows Login and returns a dataset with multiple records but only 1 distinct `EmployeeID`. I want to pass the `EmployeeID` so that I do not need to perform a conversion on the Windows Login when reporting.

I believe there is a simple C# solution to this issue, but as a novice I do not know how to declare the methods necessary.
Here is the code which successfully defaults the `CreatedBy` & `CreateDate` values, and where I want to implement the `EmployeeID` default as well

```
partial void TBG_KeepInTimesheets_Inserting(TBG_KeepInTimesheet entity)
    {
        entity.CreatedBy = this.Application.User.Name;
        entity.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
        entity.EmployeeID = LightSwitchApplication.TBG_V_KeepInTimeSheet_Detail.EmployeeID.get;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By utilising your existing filter (and assuming your Data Source is called ApplicationData) you should be able to achieve this as follows: -

```
partial void TBG_KeepInTimesheets_Inserting(TBG_KeepInTimesheet entity)
{
    entity.CreatedBy = this.Application.User.Name;
    entity.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
    entity.EmployeeID = DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.TBG_V_KeepInTimeSheet_Details.FirstOrDefault().EmployeeID;
}
```

Comment: Chris Cook you are the man! Thank you very much, I can see that bit of code coming in handy with many future projects